# Setting up in app purchases in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

These are the steps i have followed, please do tell if i did anything wrong.

1)Downloaded trivial drive demo app from http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html as it has in app purchase demo, i used its clases.

2)I got my Base64-encoded RSA public key from services and api's of my app, and put it in
String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjjHvSNj3LNLj/x+GOIwZktHendo.....AQAB"; variable.

3)Then i set up an in app purchase item in my developer account, i just gave a random name.(i feel i made a mistake here)

4)Then i updated my manifest with billing permission.

These are the only steps i did, Strictly nothing extra.

Now when ever i try to press the imageButton from the trivial drive app i get **Authentication is required. You ned to sign into your google account** .

I followed all the steps from the documentation, but cant figure out why is this hapening.

I am signed in to my google account, what steps am i missing ?

Comment: try this https://github.com/blundell/SimpleInAppPurchaseV3

Comment: until i try your code can you tell me what mistake i did

Comment: I just had to wait, it worked